# Adding a new tab in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

Today when I logged in to Gmail there were many tabs like Primary, Social, Promotions, and Updates.

Indeed I quickly googled to find that's the new tabbed layout. All is well.

But, I wonder is it possible to add a new tab like that on my own?

Say for example, can I add a tab like Test along with those that are there already? I googled out but could not find any examples of this.

Comment: Please don't use inline code tags for emphasis.

Comment: Those are Inbox categories, and no, you can't add your own. You would need to choose a different inbox style to customize it in that way. At best you can turn off some categories (excepting "Primary".) More information from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016) and the [Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/a-new-inbox-that-puts-you-back-in.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add your own tab, you can only choose: Social, Promotions, Updates, Forums etc. designed by Google.

Answer (score -1):

You can't add your own tab to your Gmail account right now.

But you can drag mail from one tab to another tab to put it there and then you will prompted:

```
The conversation has been moved to <tab>.  
Do this for future messages from <email address>?
```

If you click yes then all future mails from that e-mail address will appear under that tab.

Comment: @pnuts I think you didn't see the first line in my answer.

Comment: @pnuts : :) Now it is better. thank you.